# Is there a way to make clickable canvas in fyne golang?

Tags: go, fyne

I'm trying to make a clickable canvas in fyne golang but it's not working. I can get the Tapped and the secondaryTapped methods to work but I think there is something wrong with the show method because the image is not displaying. I really feel like the code should work but I can't find a solution.

I tried this and some other versions of it but none of them have worked

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
)

type ClickableCanvas struct {
    canvas fyne.CanvasObject
}

func NewClickableCanvas() *ClickableCanvas {
    img := canvas.NewImageFromFile("image.png")
    c := &ClickableCanvas{canvas: img}
    return c
}

func (c *ClickableCanvas) Tapped(pos *fyne.PointEvent) {
    x := pos.AbsolutePosition.X
    y := pos.AbsolutePosition.Y
    fmt.Printf("clicked at x=%f and y=%f\n", x, y)
}

func (c *ClickableCanvas) TappedSecondary(pos *fyne.PointEvent) {
    x := pos.AbsolutePosition.X
    y := pos.AbsolutePosition.Y
    fmt.Printf("Left clicked at x=%f and y=%f\n", x, y)
}

func (c *ClickableCanvas) MinSize() fyne.Size {
    return c.canvas.MinSize()
}

func (c *ClickableCanvas) Size() fyne.Size {
    return c.canvas.Size()
}

func (c *ClickableCanvas) Resize(size fyne.Size) {
    c.canvas.Resize(size)
}

func (c *ClickableCanvas) Refresh() {
    c.canvas.Refresh()
}

func (c *ClickableCanvas) Hide() {
    c.canvas.Hide()
}

func (c *ClickableCanvas) Move(ha fyne.Position) {
    c.canvas.Move(ha)
}

func (c *ClickableCanvas) Position() fyne.Position {
    return c.canvas.Position()
}

func (c *ClickableCanvas) Show() {
    c.canvas.Show()
}

func (c *ClickableCanvas) Visible() bool {
    fmt.Print(c.canvas.Visible())
    return c.canvas.Visible()
}

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    w := myApp.NewWindow("Image")
    image := NewClickableCanvas()

    w.SetContent(image)
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

I have tried w.SetContent(image.canvas) instead of w.SetContent(image) and that work as it's intended so there is nothing wrong with creating an canvas from an file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can only attach behaviours like that to a Widget, not the abstract concept of a `CanvasObject`.
If your type extended `widget.BaseWidget` instead it should work. This is the easiest way to make a custom widget https://developer.fyne.io/extend/custom-widget.